# Bedeutung des Wortes „auch“ in einem Satz im Grünen Heinrich

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, grammar-identification

Der Textabschnitt stammt aus Gottfried Kellers *Der grüne Heinrich*, ISBN 3-458-14937-6, Insel Verlag 1980, S. 218.

> Nachdem ich noch den Stall besehen und in der Scheune jeder Kuh eine Gabel voll Klee hinübergeschoben, verabschiedete ich mich; die Base ließ es sich aber nicht nehmen, mich ein Stückes Weges zu begleiten, um mich schnell noch einer anderen Base vorzustellen, wo ich mich nicht lange aufzuhalten brauchte.
> Ich fand eine freundliche Matrone, nicht ganz von dem edlen und feinen Wesen meiner Großmutter, aber doch voll Anstand und Wohlwollen. [...]
> **Sie galt für eine Art Lorelei, obschon sie Judith hieß, auch niemand etwas Bestimmtes oder Nachteiliges von ihr wußte.**

Ich verstehe den Sinn der einzelnen Satzteile:
Trotz ihres Namens, der ein frommes, kein promiskuitives Leben andeutet (vgl. Buch Judith) galt die Frau als anziehend für Männer, vielleicht mit zerstörerischem Potenzial (vgl. Loreley-Stoff z. B. bei Brentano).
Eigentlich hatte aber niemand wirklich Negatives über sie zu berichten.

Die Verwendung des *auch* erschließt sich mir nicht und ich kann sie aus dem Duden, DWDS und Grimm nicht nachvollziehen.
Ich hätte eine solche Formulierung erwartet:

> Sie galt für eine Art Lorelei, obschon sie Judith hieß, auch **wenn** niemand etwas Bestimmtes oder Nachteiliges von ihr wußte.
>
> oder: Sie galt für eine Art Lorelei, obschon sie Judith hieß, **obwohl** niemand etwas Bestimmtes oder Nachteiliges von ihr wußte.
>
> Oder: Sie galt für eine Art Lorelei, obschon sie Judith hieß, auch wusste niemand etwas Bestimmtes oder Nachteiliges von ihr.

**Wie ist der Satz (insb. das *auch*) grammatikalisch zu analysieren?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meiner Meinung nach darf man hier die Satzbestandteile (1) "obschon sie Judith hieß" und (2) "auch niemand etwas Bestimmtes oder Nachteiliges von ihr wußte" nicht getrennt voneinander betrachten. Lässt man (2) weg, so entsteht der völlig richtige und klare Satz

> Sie galt für eine Art Lorelei, obschon sie Judith hieß.

Lässt man dagegen (1) weg, so entsteht der Satz

> Sie galt für eine Art Lorelei, auch niemand etwas Bestimmtes oder Nachteiliges von ihr wußte.

Das ist gewiss kein gutes Deutsch und man spürt den Drang, das durch

> "auch wenn niemand ..."

> "obwohl niemand ... "

zu ersetzen.

"auch niemand ..." ist aber nur als Ergänzung von "obschon" zu verstehen. Es werden zwei Gründe aufgezählt und durch Komma getrennt. Hätte Keller statt des Kommas ein "und" verwendet, so wäre keine Irritation entstanden:

> Sie galt für eine Art Lorelei, obschon sie Judith hieß und auch niemand etwas Bestimmtes oder Nachteiliges von ihr wußte.

Vgl. auch den etwas längeren Satz

> Sie galt für eine Art Lorelei, obschon sie Judith hieß, niemand etwas  Nachteiliges von ihr wußte und sie überhaupt eine angenehme Person war.